# Scrapy Newbie Question - can't get tutorial file working

Tags: python, scrapy

I am a complete newbie to Python and Scrapy so I started by trying to replicate the tutorial.  I am trying to scrape the www.dmoz.org website as per the tutorial.

I compose the dmoz_spider.py as indicated below

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

from dmoz.items import DmozItem

class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
   name = "dmoz.org"
   allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
   start_urls = [
       "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
       "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
   ]

   def parse(self, response):
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       sites = hxs.select('//ul/li')
       items = []
       for site in sites:
           item = DmozItem()
           item['title'] = site.select('a/text()').extract()
           item['link'] = site.select('a/@href').extract()
           item['desc'] = site.select('text()').extract()
           items.append(item)
       return items
```

and what I am supposed to get via website is something different.
any idea what I am screwing up?

Comment: What i get is this 2010-12-16 18:42:29-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.10.3 started (bot: dmoz)
2010-12-16 18:42:29-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: TelnetConsole, SpiderCont
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python27\Scripts\scrapy", line 4, in <module>
    execute()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 130, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 96, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 136, in

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem. Make sure you made the below change as it says to do in the tutorial.

Open items.py and see if you changed class

```
class TutorialItem(Item):
    title=Field()
    link=Field()
    desc=Field()
```

into:

```
class DmozItem(Item):
    title=Field()
    link=Field()
    desc=Field()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the code you pasted. The problem must be elsewhere, can you paste the whole output you get? (your comment stops where the interesting part starts...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to go the the directory containing the settings.py file and run

scrapy crawl dmoz from there.

FOllow the structure of your project against https://github.com/scrapy/dirbot for clarity